# Google Internal App sharing - Unexpected error

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, internal-app-sharing

Suddenly from 3 days, I am not able to use Google Internal App sharing. Loading App sharing page fails with error "unexpected error". Is there anyone else who faced this issue? and have some workaround?

Note:

1. I am aware that I should raise this issue in Google support, but they are taking too much time to respond. Meanwhile, I am just searching for workarounds or possible reasons for it.
2. I have tried all possible solutions which are already there on the Web, like incognito mode, clearing cache, etc.
3. In my network those who already have play store accounts are also getting the same issue. [image]

Comment: Same here! No solution yet.

PS: Have you raised an issue at Google that I should upvote?

Comment: @Oderik : I raised this issue with Google play support team, they are working on it and they promised to get back ASAP. Communication is happening in the mail, no ticket, where you can upvote.

Comment: @Oderik : Its working now, seems like they fixed issue

Comment: great, thanks for notifying me!
(Hm, I tried to mention you but it gets removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API gateway still seems to work. I was able to upload a test apk/aab via fastlane.

It's an easy [setup](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/). Then use the [upload_to_play_store_internal_app_sharing](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store_internal_app_sharing/) command to upload the apk/aab

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the propper permissions.

Comment: @Raymond: Thanks for your input. As the Google Internal App sharing is up, I won't be trying your suggested solution. Your solution is definitely a workaround, which I was looking for. Even though the Internal App sharing page is down, we can try with Google Play developers API https://developers.google.com/android-publisher.