# Internal App Sharing in Google Play Console shows "An unexpected error occurred "

Tags: android, google-play-console, internal-app-sharing

On click on Internal App Sharing in Google Play Console. I get an error message saying "**An Unexpected error has occurred. Please try again**".  I was able to use this before. Facing this issue for a couple of days now.  Attaching a screenshot of the error message  Please check [image: Error code keeps on changing every time I try to access the page .]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851924/google-internal-app-sharing-unexpected-error. Try now its working.